# Add Jars to User LIbraries in Eclipse Helios, Mac OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, libraries

I've created a new Java project (testProject) and begin to add jars to a user library, but I'm getting project errors after adding jars to a "User Library"

Here's what I'm doing:Create the User Library

1. Right mouse click the project and click Properties
2. Click Add Library..., select User Library, and click Next
3. Click button, User Libraries...
4. Click New... and give it a name: mule; click OK.
5. Select mule and click Add JARs...
6. Add a jar (e.g. I've added two, one from the root project, log4j.jar, and another from /opt/mule/lib)
7. Click OK
8. Click Finish

Now I'm seeing a red x show on the mule library. 
 1. Click Edit, and click User Libraries
 2. The message on each jar says the library is missing, and it seems to be losing the actual path.

See attached image:
[image]

I'm running On a Mac OSX 10.5.8, running Java 
openjdk version "1.6.0-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0-internal-landonf_17_may_2009_13_58-b00)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 11.0-b17, mixed mode)

This doesn't seem to be a problem on a Vista PC, running Eclipse on Java 1.6.0_16. (Or under Ubuntu).

Is anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been a number of problems reported by people trying to run Eclipse on Open JDK. Plus it looks like you are using some sort of pre-production build of it. The first thing I'd do is to try running Eclipse with JDK that comes with Mac OSX.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried switching to the default JDK (build 1.5.0_26-b03-376-9M3263) and still see the same problem.

Comment: How did you switch? Did you update your eclipse.ini file? Are you positive that Eclipse is running with that JVM? If that's all fine, I would try to experiment in a clean workspace. The usecase you are describing is very basic and there are many Mac OSX Eclipse users, so there is something about your specific setup that is causing issues.

Comment: After a number of subtle changes, (e.g. switching workspaces, adjusting permissions, changing everything back), my problem is gone. I'm going to chalk it up to the JDK. Thanks again for the suggestion, Konstantin!

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar problem in Eclipse Indigo SR2 on a Windows XP workstation. It ran perfectly for a long time until it broke and displayed the behavior that the OP has observed.

I have found out more what causes the problem and have found a workaround.

The problem is caused when I choose Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries | Add JARS... and add a new jar file. What happens is that although the user library is given an absolute path (`C:\Documents and Settings\a23456\box_corefx\1box-corefx\box-build\target\deployment\weblogic\APP-INF\lib\antlr-2.7.6.jar`) it only stores a relative path (`\1box-corefx\box-build\target\deployment\weblogic\APP-INF\lib\antlr-2.7.6.jar`). This relative path is what makes it say "missing."

The workaround is to export a good user library and massage the jars so that it has entries like:

```
<archive path="C:/Documents and Settings/a23456/box_corefx/1box-corefx/box-build/target/deployment/weblogic/APP-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
```

Then import the new user library.